# Executing a threading program in Linux

Tags: linux, multithreading, process

Here is my code. When I try to compile, it gives me numerous errors.  I used gcc -o process process.c -lpthread. Can anyone help me? Ive tried inlcuding "mamespace" but that doesnt help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main()
{
  int i, j;
  int Num_of_children = 0;
  pid_t pid[10];
  pid_t return_pid;

  return_pid = fork();
  if(return_pid > 0) {
     pid[Num_of_children] = return_pid;
     Num_of_children = Num_of_children + 1;
  }

  return_pid = fork();
  if(return_pid > 0) {
     pid[Num_of_children] = return_pid;
     Num_of_children = Num_of_children + 1;
  }
  else { Num_of_children = 0; }

  if (Num_of_children > 0) {
     return_pid = fork();
     if(return_pid > 0) {
        pid[Num_of_children] = return_pid;
        Num_of_children = Num_of_children + 1;
     }
     else { Num_of_children = 0; }
  }
   for(j=0; j<3; j++) {
      sleep(1+1000*rand()/RAND_MAX);
      printf("PID: %d, Iteration: d%\n", getpid(), i);
   }
  for(j=0; j<Num_of_children; j++) waitpid(pid[j], NULL, 0);
}
```

Comment: The philosophy for providing debugging help here is that of requiring a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  You will learn a great deal about debugging when you cut back your code into smaller portions that reproduce the first of these "compiling errors" (which are not otherwise described in your Question).

Comment: @hardmath process.c:39:1: error: stray ‘\240’ in program
process.c:39:1: error: stray ‘\302’ in program
process.c:39:1: error: stray ‘\240’ in program
process.c:40:1: error: stray ‘\302’ in program
   for(j=0; j<Num_of_children; j++) waitpid(pid[j], NULL, 0);
 ^
process.c:40:1: error: stray ‘\240’ in program
process.c:40:1: error: stray ‘\302’ in program
process.c:40:1: error: stray ‘\240’ in program

Answer (score 1):

Build your program with warnings turned on, that is `gcc -Wall -g -lpthread process.c -o process`. Then you'll find the errors you made in your code:

```
process.c: In function ‘main’:
process.c:38:7: warning: unknown conversion type character 0xa in format [-Wformat=]
       printf("PID: %d, Iteration: d%\n", getpid(), i);
       ^
process.c:38:7: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
process.c:41:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
process.c:38:7: warning: ‘i’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
       printf("PID: %d, Iteration: d%\n", getpid(), i);
       ^
```

So fix the errors and rebuild it.